# Unable to establish pppoe connection

Tags: linux, networking, ppp, pppd

I have the issue while establishing pppoe connection on De(b)vuan based distribution.
My ISP allows me to establish link via tagged vlan 300. Previosly the connection worked just fine, before i slightly recompiled kernel (made it more generic), but I don't believe it should be a problem.

All modules are (should) be properly loaded already.

Here is the log:

```
Nov 11 01:08:02  pppd[2863]: Send PPPOE Discovery V1T1 PADI session 0x0 length 12
Nov 11 01:08:02  pppd[2863]:  dst ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff  src b8:27:eb:62:e6:80
Nov 11 01:08:02  pppd[2863]:  [service-name] [host-uniq  2f 0b 00 00]
Nov 11 01:08:02  pppd[2863]: Recv PPPOE Discovery V1T1 PADO session 0x0 length 53
Nov 11 01:08:02  pppd[2863]:  dst b8:27:eb:62:e6:80  src e4:81:84:26:2e:6c
Nov 11 01:08:02  pppd[2863]:  [service-name] [AC-name BNG_NS_SATELIT1_2] [host-uniq  2f 0b 00 00] [AC-cookie  06 40 99 9b 50 e9 b3 90 be 93 bb 10 9f e6 16 db]
Nov 11 01:08:02  pppd[2863]: Send PPPOE Discovery V1T1 PADR session 0x0 length 32
Nov 11 01:08:02  pppd[2863]:  dst e4:81:84:26:2e:6c  src b8:27:eb:62:e6:80
Nov 11 01:08:02  pppd[2863]:  [service-name] [host-uniq  2f 0b 00 00] [AC-cookie  06 40 99 9b 50 e9 b3 90 be 93 bb 10 9f e6 16 db]
Nov 11 01:08:02  pppd[2863]: Recv PPPOE Discovery V1T1 PADO session 0x0 length 57
Nov 11 01:08:02  pppd[2863]:  dst b8:27:eb:62:e6:80  src e4:81:84:25:df:d6
Nov 11 01:08:02  pppd[2863]:  [service-name] [AC-name BNG_XXXX] [host-uniq  2f 0b 00 00] [AC-cookie  5e 0c 8b 60 fb 75 10 fd 83 4f 68 ce fa 5a f3 d9]
Nov 11 01:08:02  pppd[2863]: Recv PPPOE Discovery V1T1 PADS session 0x642 length 12
Nov 11 01:08:02  pppd[2863]:  dst b8:27:eb:62:e6:80  src e4:81:84:26:2e:6c
Nov 11 01:08:02  pppd[2863]:  [service-name] [host-uniq  2f 0b 00 00]
Nov 11 01:08:02  pppd[2863]: PADS: Service-Name: ''
Nov 11 01:08:02  pppd[2863]: PPP session is 1602
Nov 11 01:08:02  pppd[2863]: Connected to e4:81:xx:xx:xx via interface eth0.300
Nov 11 01:08:02  pppd[2863]: using channel 71
Nov 11 01:08:02  pppd[2863]: Using interface ppp0
Nov 11 01:08:02  pppd[2863]: Connect: ppp0 <--> eth0.300
Nov 11 01:08:02  pppd[2863]: sent [LCP ConfReq id=0xa <mru 1492> <magic 0x6bd07e40>]
Nov 11 01:08:02  pppd[2863]: rcvd [LCP ConfAck id=0xa <mru 1492> <magic 0x6bd07e40>]
Nov 11 01:08:05  pppd[2863]: rcvd [LCP ConfReq id=0x28 <mru 1492> <auth pap> <magic 0x6e7eeffa>]
Nov 11 01:08:05  pppd[2863]: sent [LCP ConfAck id=0x28 <mru 1492> <auth pap> <magic 0x6e7eeffa>]
Nov 11 01:08:05  pppd[2863]: sent [LCP EchoReq id=0x0 magic=0x6bd07e40]
Nov 11 01:08:05  pppd[2863]: sent [PAP AuthReq id=0x9 user="username@isp.com" password=<hidden>]
Nov 11 01:08:05  pppd[2863]: rcvd [LCP EchoRep id=0x0 magic=0x6e7eeffa]
Nov 11 01:08:06  pppd[2863]: rcvd [PAP AuthAck id=0x9 "Login ok"]
Nov 11 01:08:06  pppd[2863]: Remote message: Login ok
Nov 11 01:08:06  pppd[2863]: PAP authentication succeeded
Nov 11 01:08:06  pppd[2863]: peer from calling number E4:81:xx:xx:xx:xx authorized
Nov 11 01:08:06  pppd[2863]: sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x19 <addr 0.0.0.0>]
Nov 11 01:08:06  pppd[2863]: rcvd [IPCP ConfReq id=0xe <addr xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx>]
Nov 11 01:08:06  pppd[2863]: sent [IPCP ConfAck id=0xe <addr xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx>] # <- GW
Nov 11 01:08:06  pppd[2863]: rcvd [IPCP ConfNak id=0x19 <addr xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx>]
Nov 11 01:08:06  pppd[2863]: sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x1a <addr xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx>]
Nov 11 01:08:06  pppd[2863]: rcvd [IPCP ConfAck id=0x1a <addr xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx>]
Nov 11 01:08:06  pppd[2863]: ioctl(SIOCADDRT) device route: Network is down (line 2501)
Nov 11 01:08:06  pppd[2863]: Interface configuration failed
Nov 11 01:08:06  pppd[2863]: Connect time 0.1 minutes.
Nov 11 01:08:06  pppd[2863]: Sent 30 bytes, received 30 bytes.
Nov 11 01:08:06  pppd[2863]: sent [IPCP TermReq id=0x1b "Interface configuration failed"]
Nov 11 01:08:06  pppd[2863]: rcvd [LCP TermReq id=0x29]
Nov 11 01:08:06  pppd[2863]: LCP terminated by peer
Nov 11 01:08:06  pppd[2863]: sent [LCP TermAck id=0x29]
Nov 11 01:08:06  pppd[2863]: rcvd [IPCP TermAck id=0x1b]
Nov 11 01:08:06  pppd[2863]: Discarded non-LCP packet when LCP not open
Nov 11 01:08:06  pppd[2863]: Modem hangup
Nov 11 01:08:06  pppd[2863]: Connection terminated.
Nov 11 01:08:06  pppd[2863]: Failed to disconnect PPPoE socket: 114 Operation already in progress


 # cat /etc/ppp/peers/dsl-provider 
# Minimalistic default options file for DSL/PPPoE connections

noipdefault
defaultroute
replacedefaultroute
hide-password
#lcp-echo-interval 0 
#lcp-echo-failure 0
noauth
persist
mtu 1412
persist
#maxfail 0
holdoff 20
plugin rp-pppoe.so
eth0.300
user "username@isp.com"
```

**EDIT:** As it is on my modified router, here is the link status :

```
# ip  a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,PROMISC,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether b8:27:eb:62:e6:80 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 fe80::ba27:ebff:fe62:e680/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:0e:c6:c7:3e:1c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.1/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global eth1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::20e:c6ff:fec7:3e1c/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: eth3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast master br0 state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:e0:4c:36:02:76 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 fe80::2e0:4cff:fe36:276/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
32: eth0.200@eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master br0 state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether b8:27:eb:62:e6:80 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 fe80::ba27:ebff:fe62:e680/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
33: br0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:e0:4c:36:02:76 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 fe80::2e0:4cff:fe36:276/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
63: eth0.300@eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether b8:27:eb:62:e6:80 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 fe80::ba27:ebff:fe62:e680/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Modules:

`# lsmod  | grep 'ppp\|802\|garp'`:

```
ppp_mppe                6951  0 
pppoe                  11779  0 
pppox                   2913  1 pppoe
ppp_generic            29613  3 pppox,pppoe,ppp_mppe
slhc                    5959  1 ppp_generic
8021q                  22998  0 
garp                    7049  1 8021q
mrp                     8903  1 8021q
stp                     2430  2 garp,bridge
llc                     5903  3 garp,bridge,stp
```

Can anyone point me what is causing:

```
Nov 11 01:08:29  pppd[2863]: ioctl(SIOCADDRT) device route: Network is down (line 2501)
Nov 11 01:08:29  pppd[2863]: Interface configuration failed
Nov 11 01:08:29  pppd[2863]: Connect time 0.1 minutes.
Nov 11 01:08:29  pppd[2863]: Sent 30 bytes, received 30 bytes.
Nov 11 01:08:29  pppd[2863]: sent [IPCP TermReq id=0x1e "Interface configuration failed"]
Nov 11 01:08:29  pppd[2863]: rcvd [LCP TermReq id=0x34]
Nov 11 01:08:29  pppd[2863]: LCP terminated by peer
```

**Edit** interfaces file:

```
 # cat /etc/network/interfaces

# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface

auto eth0
auto eth1
auto eth3

#LAN
iface eth1 inet static
    address 192.168.1.1
    netmask 255.255.255.0

#IPTV
auto eth0.200
iface eth0.200 inet manual


#WAN
auto eth0.300
iface eth0.300 inet manual

auto dsl-provider
iface dsl-provider inet ppp
    pre-up /bin/ip link set eth0.300 up # line maintained by pppoeconf
    provider dsl-provider

iface br0 inet manual
    bridge_ports eth3 eth0.200
```

IP route:

```
 # ip r
192.168.1.0/24 dev eth1  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.1.1
```

Generated by pppoeconf:

```
:/~ # grep -v '^$\|^#' /etc/ppp/peers/dsl-provider 
noipdefault
defaultroute
hide-password
lcp-echo-interval 20
lcp-echo-failure 3
connect /bin/true
noauth
persist
mtu 1492
noaccomp
default-asyncmap
logfile /var/log/ppp.log
plugin rp-pppoe.so eth0.300
user "myusername@isp.com"
```

Edit 2:

Attached strace output:

```
strace pppd file /etc/ppp/peers/dsl-provider debug
```

http://paste.debian.net/995356/

```
strace -p PID
```

http://paste.debian.net/995357/

Appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
ioctl(SIOCADDRT) device route: Network is down
```

means that `pppd` tried to set a route for an address range on a device which is down. The same happens if you set the route manually with `ip route`.

Debug by doing `ip addr`, looking at the addresses on the network interfaces and which ones are up or down, and looking at the addresses `pppd` received. This may involve some guessing what `pppd` was doing during the execution, as the state after it shuts down may not be the same state as during the execution. If you can't guess anything, use `strace` and be prepared for a large output.

You didn't show the other network interfaces or the addresses, so I can't do that for you.

Comment: thanks for response! I updated my question. I guessed that is the problem and meaning of the message, but all ifaces are up, except `ppp0` . Shouldn't this device be configured automatically when connection is going to be started? Default route, and related routing should be set with `defaultroute` && `noipdefault` in ppp.conf, right?

Comment: Hm. Possibly `pppd` is not setting `ppp0` up before trying to set the route, and that worked with older kernels? Can you upgrade `pppd` to the newest version (if this is a bug for newer kernels, I'm sure someone has noticed it already ...)?

Comment: Not sure, I haven't changed the kernel it self, only added couple of modules, it is `4.9.59` for raspberry 3. But yea, I believe this is the case. Reinstalled everything related to `ppp`  already - but no luck. When I do a reboot, i notice `ppp0` link but it is in down state. When I try to start ppp - it just get lost. Not sure how to troubleshoot this

Comment: Next step is either `strace`, or using a debugger on `pppd`, I suppose.

Comment: Well, `strace` doesn't ring a bell for me.. I am not very comfortable with low-level debug except something is obvious. If anyone can help, I'll be very thankful!